# How do I validate forms in multiple tr inside a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have multiple forms inside table in each tr like this but when clicking on save validation is not working. I want to validate parent form of .save button. Does anyone know how can I do this?

/// jquery

```
$tableID.on('click', '.save', function() {      
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    var $form =  tr.find("form");        
    $form.validate({
        rules: {
            job_step: "required",            
        },
        submitHandler: function() { 
            alert("Submitted!") 
        }
    });        
    console.log($form.valid());
});
```

Comment: Please include the HTML.  You can't put a `form` "inside a `tr`" - the browser will automatically fix your broken HTML by moving the offending HTML.  So if you try `table tr > form > td` you get `form + table > tr > td`

Comment: *"I want to validate parent form of .save button"* - we don't even know what you're talking about when you don't show a form or a save button in your code.  Based on the code you've shown, it looks like you should go take some time to carefully study the documentation and examples.  https://jqueryvalidation.org  Also wouldn't hurt to use the SO search function and look at other similar jQuery Validate questions.